# I have issue with the query execution time in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is the My Query:

```
SELECT mm.b_id AS b_user_id, mm.v_seo_url AS v_seo_url, C.b_id AS b_conversion_id, mm.v_first_name AS v_first_name, mm.v_last_name AS v_last_name, R.b_id AS b_message_id, R.t_message AS t_message, R.b_read_flag AS b_read_flag, R.d_date_time AS d_date_time
FROM mycom_member mm, mycom_conversation C, mycom_conversation_replay R
JOIN (

SELECT MAX( t1.d_date_time ) AS time
FROM mycom_conversation_replay t1
GROUP BY t1.b_conversation_id
ORDER BY t1.b_id DESC
) AS recent ON recent.time = R.d_date_time
WHERE CASE WHEN C.b_user_one_id =10
THEN C.b_user_two_id = mm.b_id
AND C.v_user_one_status = 'enable'
WHEN C.b_user_two_id =10
THEN C.b_user_one_id = mm.b_id
AND C.v_user_two_status = 'enable'
END AND C.b_id = R.b_conversation_id
AND (
C.b_user_one_id =10
OR C.b_user_two_id =10
)
GROUP BY R.b_conversation_id
ORDER BY R.b_id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

I have 300000 Records in conversation_replay table and I get the 100 Records.
It's take the 3.7918 sec.So How can I slow the query execution time.

Comment: slow it? you mean make it faster right? and to answer that - show us the `explain` output and the table schema

Comment: The case statements are little weird `CASE WHEN C.b_user_one_id =10
THEN C.b_user_two_id = mm.b_id
AND C.v_user_one_status = 'enable'
WHEN C.b_user_two_id =10`

Comment: execution  id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  PRIMARY  C  index_merge  PRIMARY,user_one,user_two  user_one,user_two  8,8  NULL 49  Using union(user_one,user_two); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  PRIMARY  R  ref  c_id_fk  c_id_fk  8  mydev_db.C.b_id  120  
1  PRIMARY  <derived2>  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 1225  Using where; Using join buffer
1  PRIMARY  mm  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 10983  Using where; Using join buffer
2  DERIVED  t1  index  NULL c_id_fk  8  NULL 299221  Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: ugh. please put that in the question and format it so a human can actually read it.